# Location of Voltage regulator on the pi-star zero

Tags: power-supply

My pi-star is overheating and turning off. I was told that it may be the voltage regulator. Is this possible and where is it located or do you have a schematic for the pi-star.

Comment: I am confused.  I know pi-star is software.  Do you have a very old hardware version of pi-star? But if your pi-star is installed in Rpi, then use a good regulator, say 5.1V+ 2.5A+, and also use heatsink for the Rpi.

Comment: If your Raspberry Pi is overheating you've done some damage to it (usually by shorting GPIO pins or connecting 3.3V to 5V). You will need to get the $35 fix in a very short amount of time.

Comment: What is a pi-star